# iPhone Audio Effects

Tags: iphone, audio, effects

I'm searching for Library, Framework or SDK for add audio effects in Objective-C, like reverber, echo etc...

Somebody knowns something?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best solution is to find a `C` library for the effects that you need. (`Objective C` code can call `C` library routines without any difficulty).

Answer (score 1):

[FMOD](http://www.fmod.org/index.php/products/fmodex) is a great suite of audio processing effects and runs well on iPhone.

There are a few good open-source collections, [mda-vst](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mda-vst/), for example, but you'll have to hook them into iOS audio frameworks yourself. I'm not aware of any that are ready to go for iOS off the shelf.